# Repetitive Problems With DIY Arduino EEG

Tags: arduino, diy

I'm a hobbyist with only minor electronics experience trying to construct an EEG machine as part of a basic brain-computer interface. I'm following [this](https://erkutlu.blogspot.com/2012/12/eeg-and-arduino-do-it-yourself-eeg-ekg.html) tutorial for a DIY EEG using an arduino, but I've been struggling for a few weeks to resolve a problem in the preamp circuit. I'm using this circuit diagram:

[image: Schematic]

I think I've isolated the problem to the 3130 (and surrounding components) between the 15k resistor and the analog input because when I place the analog input directly after the 15K resistor next to the 10uF capacitor, I get very noisy, but seemingly valid, input. Here's a short [video](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?ui=2&ik=904e722b07&attid=0.1&permmsgid=msg-a:r-1175753792639655306&th=173d140edeb48925&view=att&disp=safe&realattid=f_kdmiwoxc1) of the graph when I connect the electrodes under these conditions. However, when I wire up the high amplification/filtering section containing the top right 3130 I either get an issue where output holds the maximum value (1023 or 5v) regardless of electrode connections or I get a nearly flat line with only tiny, random variations independent of electrode connections.

Oddly, unplugging the .68uF capacitor to ground enables output when I have the latter problem, but the output is heavy in noise and very erratic. When I have the former issue (maxed out input), doing so zeroes output completely.

I'm unsure of how to proceed as, at this point, I've built the circuit six times with little change. I was hoping for suggestions I could use to continue troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: The link to your schematic is gone. Please post schematics directly into your question. We cannot help you without a schematic.

Comment: fixed, i think.

Comment: The circuit is not complete. Normally an electrode connects to each ear lobe and that becomes signal ground. Without grounding your inputs will overload. An EEG has a lot of LF gain.

Comment: Okay, cool. Are two grounding electrodes used out of necessity? Should I add a second neutral electrode or should I connect the signal ground to ground?

Comment: Those "two" electrodes from each ear lobe go to a differential op-amp, who's output becomes the virtual signal ground. Coupled to power ground with 100 nF capacitor and 1 meg resistor. NEVER Earth ground this device, run it isolated by transformer or power supply.